# Express static js file not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to load "vanilla-calendar-min.js" in header.ejs. The alert in "vanilla-calendar-min.js" is not getting invoked so I think "vanilla-calendar-min.js" is not getting loade. Please help me find the mistake. Thanks in advance.
app.js

```
const express = require("express");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

header.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vanilla-calendar-min.css">
<script src="js/vanilla-calendar-min.js"></script>
```

vanilla-calendar-min.js

```
alert("hello");
```

Directory structure
[image]

Comment: Change to this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/vanilla-calendar-min.css">` and `<script src="/js/vanilla-calendar-min.js"></script>`.  Don't use path-relative links to resources in your HTML as that makes the resource's location be dependent upon the url path of the current HTML page which is almost never what you want.

Comment: Also, if you look in the browser debug console, it will show you exactly what resources aren't getting loaded - you don't need an `alert()` to tell you that.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank u for replying but it did not work

Comment: @jfriend00 it is actually not giving any error in browser console which is actually strange.

Comment: Please provide the full path to `vanilla-calendar-min.js` on your disk and provide the full path of `__dirname` when in `app.js`.  Only with that info, can we make further recommendations.  FYI, files that the browser cannot download because the URL is wrong WILL show an error in the browser console.  If you're not seeing that type of error, then either the browser is successfully download the file just fine or you're not looking in the right place for the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 files got loaded properly now, There was someother mistake that I did. Thank u!